# login unsuccessfull on clicking button?

Tags: java, jdbc

I have a table:

```
create table User1(Username varchar2(20) ,
 First_Name varchar2(20) ,
 Last_Name varchar2(20) , 
Password varchar2(20) ,
 Date_Of_Birth Date )
```

following jdbc code::

```
if(e.getSource()==submit)
        {
        Connection con=null;
        ResultSet rs=null;
        PreparedStatement st=null;
        try
        {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
             con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1522:xe", "hr", "hr");
            st=con.prepareStatement("select count(1) from User1 where Username = ? and Password = ? ");
            //st.setParameter(1, text1.getText());
            //st.setParameter(2, p1.getText());
            st.setString(1,text1.getText());
            st.setString(2,text1.getText());
             rs= st.executeQuery();
            //String t1=text1.getText();
            //String t2= p1.getText();
        while(rs.next())
        {
            if (rs.getInt(1) == 1)
                 {
                 new Rec_options();
                }
        }
        }
        catch(SQLException ee)
        {
        System.out.println(ee);
        }
        catch(Exception e1)
        {
        System.out.println(e1);
        }
        finally
        {
        try
        {
         rs.close();
         con.close();
        st.close();
        }
        catch(SQLException eee)
        {
        System.out.println(eee);
        }
        }
        }
```

Is there a problem in while loop ? cause after entering username and password when i click on submit button ,another page "Rec_options" should get opened,but here nothing's happening nor am i getting any error or something in cmd.I'm entering the correct username and password.
Please help!!
Thanks..

Comment: One mistake I see that you are setting both the parameters with same value

    `st.setString(1,text1.getText());
    st.setString(2,text1.getText());
    //You are using text1 in both the places`

is this causing issue?

Comment: oops,didn't noticed that .thankss..yup it worked..

Answer (score 0):

You've used "st.setString(1,text1.getText());" twice. I think you should change second one to password string.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a typo in your construction of the prepared statement:

```
st.setString(1,text1.getText());
st.setString(2,text1.getText());   //   <---- You are passing your username twice.
```

Comment: yeah!! i didn't noticed that,i use too many comments while coding if i change anything ,didn't noticed that..thanks

Comment: @user3367768: These types of errors will most likely keep haunting you till your end of days ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use variable name that indicate its type and purpose

```
txtuser

txtpassword
```